# Haskell: Mirroring a Binary Tree error: "Couldn't match expected type"

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

So I am trying to design a function to return a binary tree that is a mirror of the originally sent binary tree. I think I have it almost done but I am getting  a weird "Couldn't match expected type. Here is my code:

```
mirror :: BinTree a -> BinTree a    
mirror (Node x tL tR) = Node x (mirror tR) (mirror tL)
```

**And here is the error:**

```
hw1.hs:84:30:
    Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `BinTree a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for mirror :: BinTree a -> BinTree a
          at hw1.hs:83:11
    In the first argument of `Node', namely `x'
    In the expression: Node x (mirror tR) (mirror tL)
    In an equation for `mirror':
        mirror (Node tL x tR) = Node x (mirror tR) (mirror tL)

hw1.hs:84:33:
    Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `BinTree a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for mirror :: BinTree a -> BinTree a
          at hw1.hs:83:11
    In the return type of a call of `mirror'
    In the second argument of `Node', namely `(mirror tR)'
    In the expression: Node x (mirror tR) (mirror tL)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

**It was my fault. My definition of the tree was different.**

```
data BinTree a = Empty | Node (BinTree a) a (BinTree a) deriving (Eq,Show)
```

**The new function is supposed to be : **

```
mirror :: BinTree a -> BinTree a
mirror Empty = Empty
mirror (Node tL x tR) = Node (mirror tR) x (mirror tL)
```

Comment: Can you post your definition for `BinTree a`?  Your code compiles for me.

Comment: Ah sir . Thank you!! I am so new to haskell that I forgot to check the definition of my binary tree... It was Node tL x tR and not Node x tL tR ... Thank you!

Comment: Good! Now what happens if you `mirror Empty`?

Comment: Honestly not sure waht happens. I actually did the following: mirror Empty = Empty since I have to return a BinTree?

Comment: @bheklilr You should turn your comment into answer since it solved the problem, you will get credit for solving the problem, and it will make the answer statistics for Haskell tagged SO questions better as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At @Davorak's suggestion, I'm turning my comment into an answer, even though it didn't really answer the question, just illuminated the problem.

---

When using the definition

```hs
data BinTree a = Empty | Node a (BinTree a) (BinTree a) deriving (Eq)
```

OP's original code compiles, but did not compile because the definition he was using was

```hs
data BinTree a = Empty | Node (BinTree a) a (BinTree a) deriving (Eq)
```

By modifying the function `mirror` to pattern match on the correct definition of `BinTree a`, the problem was solved.